# Unable to instantiate service > java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I save config with `SharedPreferences` and load it in class extends Services.

But error appear when I try get values of config, error like:

> Unable to instantiate service kr.co.composer.callrecord.recorder.CallRecordService: java.lang.NullPointerException

at line:

`final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

In layout `Configuration` I save a EditText:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

serverUrl.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave", ""));
serverUrl.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after)
    {
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
    }
});
```

And in the other class, I want to get this values by this code:

```
public class CallRecordService extends Service {
    final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        serverURL =(mSharedPreference.getString("autoSave", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `mSharedPreference` initialization to inside `onCreate()`, and remove the `final` modifier.

Comment: It seems like your context is null

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. Your answer is working. Please add to answer to accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @VănLộc That's cool. Simple fix. You can accept one of the posted answers, if one of them helped you. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. you're awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)** is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference, having the null value.

**Don't**

```
  public class CallRecordService extends Service {
    final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    // Call this in your onCreate() section .
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        serverURL =(mSharedPreference.getString("autoSave", ""));
    }
}
```

**Do**

```
 public class CallRecordService extends Service {
    final SharedPreferences mSharedPreference= 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); // You can pass context here
        serverURL =(mSharedPreference.getString("autoSave", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: @IntelliJ Just FYI: The OP is talking about a `Service`; you quoted the docs for `Activity`. Also, a `final` field can only be assigned in a constructor. If you meant to show the `mSharedPreference` initialization in `onCreate()`, you need to remove the `final` modifier in the declaration, and add `mSharedPreference =` in front of the first line in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Sir .Mine mistake .Thanks for your keen info.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call getApplicationContext() before onCreate().  Instead, you can do it like this:

```
public class CallRecordService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        serverURL = sp.getString("autoSave", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I resolved my problem.